# HTML javascript functions

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have created html file that contains a javascript function taking inputs from user and making some operations.When the user selects shape from dropdown list and area  or  perimeter  from  radio  button,  the area or perimeter  are  calculated  according  to  the selection.When the user selects rectangular from dropdown list, `Side2 for rectangle` must be active.
I have a problem with `functions`. I read a lof of sources about this topic but I couldn't understand how do I do that. I didn't know how do I take from user and How do I handle them.
Please help me..!

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset = "utf-8">
            <title>ShapeCalculator</title>

        </head>
        <body>
        <div>
            <p>Shape:
            <select id = "geometric" onchange = "compute()"> 
                <option value = "square">Square</option>
                <option value = "circle">Circle</option>
                <option value = "rectangle">Rectangle</option>
                <option value = "equilateraltriangle">Equilateral Triangle</option>
            </select>
            </p>
            <br><br><br>
        </div>

        <div class = "duzen">
            <form id = "radBut">
                    <input type = "radio" id = "s1" value = "perimeter">Perimeter<br>
                    <input type = "radio" id = "s1" value = "area">Area<br>
            </form>
            <br><br>
        </div>

        <div class = "duzen1">
                <form>
                    <label>Side/Radius:</label><input type = "text" id = "length1"><br>
                    <label>Side2 for Rectangle:</label><input type = "text" id = "length2"><br>
                </form>
        </div>
        <div class = "duzen2">
            <form>
                <input type="button" id = "Calculate" value = "Calculate">
                <input type="submit" id = "Reset" value = "Reset">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class = "duzen1">
                <form>
                    <label>Result is:</label><input type = "text" id  = "length3"><br>
                </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My question is that just asking you little help, just show me a way how can I do?How can I show my error or where is my error?
I improved my functions but Code don't give a result. The edited version =>

```
   <script>         
            document.getElementById('Calculate').onclick = compute;
            document.getElementById('length2').disabled=true;
            function compute(){
                var elem1 = document.getElementById('geometric').value;
                var elem2 = document.getElementById('s1');

                var x = document.getElementById('length1').value;
                var y = document.getElementById('length2').value;

                var num1 = parseFloat(x);
                var num2 = parseFloat(y);
                var num3;

                if(elem1 == 'square'){
                    document.getElementById('length2').disabled=true;
                    if(elem2[0].checked){
                        num3 = 2*(num1 + num1);
                        document.getElementById('length3').value = num3;
                    }else if(elem2[1].checked){
                        num3 = num1 * num1;
                        document.getElementById('length3').value = num3;
                    }
                }else if(elem1 == 'circle'){
                    document.getElementById('length2').disabled=true;
                    if(elem2[0].checked){
                        num3 = 2 * Math.PI * num1;
                        document.getElementById('length3').value = num3;
                    }else if(elem2[1].checked){
                        num3 = Math.PI * num1 * num1;
                        document.getElementById('length3').value = num3;
                    }
                }else if(elem1 == 'rectangle'){
                    document.getElementById('length2').disabled=false;
                    if(elem2[0].checked){
                        num3 = 2*(num1 + num2);
                        document.getElementById('length3').value = num3;
                    }else if(elem2[1].checked){
                        num3 = num1 * num2;
                        document.getElementById('length3').value = num3;
                    }
                }else if(elem1 == 'equilateraltriangle'){
                    document.getElementById('length2').disabled=true;
                    if(elem2[0].checked){
                        num3 = 3*(num1);
                        document.getElementById('length3').value = num3;
                    }else if(elem2[1].checked){
                        num3 = (num1 * num1 * Math.sqrt(3)) / 4;
                        document.getElementById('length3').value = num3;
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: `"I have a problem with functions"` - And what would that problem *be*, exactly?

Comment: But you are not doing anything with you function!! the if and else block are emepty.

Comment: You are not returning/doing anything in your function

Comment: What do you want to do with your function??

Comment: if the selected item circle, code will compute its area or perimeter acording to radio button. @David,@chsdk,@Han Arantes,@James Thorpe,@Jorge Mejia

Comment: @Theory: So you're asking us how to compute the area or the perimeter of a shape?  That's not really a programming question, that's a basic geometry question.  And you can look it up very easily on Google.

Comment: No,I don't know to use in functions that geometric operation.How can I use them in these function.How can I invoke them? @David

Comment: I think you are asking how to enable, field accordingly to user choice in the dropdwon?!

Comment: @Theory: So basically, "How do I write JavaScript code?"  You might want to start with some introductory tutorials on JavaScript.  At the moment it seems like you're just trying to get us to do your homework for you.

Comment: You have high reputation but you don't try to help a person that is new at html and you put an obstacle in front. If I am good at html. I understand that question and give an answer instead of put an obstacle. @David

Comment: @Theory: It's worth noting that you've *significantly* changed the question since that comment was posted. At the time, you had almost *no* code and your only question essentially boiled down to "How do I do JavaScript?" Stack Overflow can be very helpful, but we don't provide end-to-end tutorials. Starting with some introductory tutorials in JavaScript would benefit you tremendously. Now that you have code, debugging that code to gather information on further problems would be the way to go. Good luck, and try not to be personally offended when someone doesn't do all of your work for you.

Comment: I didn't say that do all of my work for me. You just could show a way or make a small start like aless80, chsdk, and user3053677. Okey I was able to reach the conclusion thanks to them. and Thank you anyway. @David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply hide/make visible that "Side2 for Ractangle" like this:

```
function setShape(shape) {
   var elem = document.getElementById('geometric').value;
   if(elem == "rectangle"){
      console.log('rectangle: make side2 visible')
      document.getElementById('side2label').style.visibility = 'visible';
      document.getElementById('side2input').hidden=false
   }else{
      console.log('not rectangle: hide side2')
      document.getElementById('side2label').style.visibility="hidden"
      document.getElementById('side2input').hidden=true
   }
}
```

using this html:

```
<form>
<label>Side/Radius:</label><input type = "text" name = "length1">
<br>
<label id="side2label" style="visibility:hidden">Side2 for Rectangle:</label>                    
<input id="side2input" type = "text" name = "length2" hidden><br>
</form>
```

It is not super elegant but it could be what you need. Later on you might want to use a css class and in the function attach that class to the html  elements you want to hide/make visible

**Edit:** You wrote a function but you get no result. There is a lot to do to your code. For example, the Perimeter and Area radio buttons do not exclude each other and stay selected. you have two elements with id="s1", (see my comments above to your question) and who knows what else is not correct.
This should get you going but it is up to you to check the details (elem2 refers to which element?) and if the results are correct:

```
if(elem1 == 'square'){
   document.getElementById('length2').disabled=true;
   if(elem2.checked){
     console.log("if")
     num3 = 2*(num1 + num1);
     document.getElementById('length3').value = num3;
   }else if(elem2.checked){
      console.log("else if")
      num3 = num1 * num1;
      document.getElementById('length3').value = num3;
   }
} else if ....
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. @aless80

Comment: Can you help me again? I improved my function. @aless80

Comment: You've been really helpful. Especially pressing f12 that you metioned. I thank you so much.Finally I finished and can take correct result. @aless80

Comment: I am glad that helped! Good luck in the future

Answer (score 2):

If I have got your question properly .....
 You are expecting a code that makes the side2 disabled for all the options except rectangle.
**Do not look at all the code I have uploaded.... check two things..**
1. I have added an id for side2 labeled textbox.
2. The javascript snippet is slightly modified... rest of your html code is as it was.
     I removed unnecessary css and javascript codes and posting it.... please comment whether it is useful to you.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p>
            <select id = "geometric" onchange="myFunction()"> 
                <option value = "square">Square</option>
                <option value = "circle">Circle</option>
                <option value = "rectangle">Rectangle</option>
                <option value = "equilateraltriangle">Equilateral Triangle</option>
            </select>
            </p>
            <br><br><br>
        </div>

        <div class = "duzen">
            <form name = "radBut">
                    <input type = "radio" name = "shape1" value = "perimeter">Perimeter<br>
                    <input type = "radio" name = "shape2" value = "area">Area<br>
            </form>
            <br><br>
        </div>

        <div class = "duzen1">
                <form>
                    <label>Side/Radius:</label><input type = "text" name = "length1"><br>
                    <label>Side2 for Rectangle:</label><input type = "text" name = "length2" id="do_active"><br>
                </form>
        </div>
        <div class = "duzen2">
            <form>
                <input type="submit" name = "calculate" value="Calculate">
                <input type="submit" name = "reset" value="Reset">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class = "duzen1">
                <form>
                    <label>Result is:</label><input type = "text" name = "length3"><br>
                </form>
        </div>

        <script>
        document.getElementById('do_active').disabled=true;         
            function myFunction() {
                var elem = document.getElementById('geometric').value;
                if(elem == 'rectangle'){
            document.getElementById('do_active').disabled=false;
                }else{
            document.getElementById('do_active').disabled=true;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much,this is very helpful for me. @user3053677

Comment: Can you help me again? I improved my function. @user3053677

Comment: are you aware of the console in your browser? If you press F12 and go to the console. The console will show errors when you use your application. For example, I see "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined" when I change the shape. This means that all those elem2[1].checked are wrong because elem2[1] are undefined. You should study how to get a html element, you are probably confused between getElementById and getElementsByName. Go and study what the output of these methods are, and try them on your browser's console

Comment: you also have two elements with the same s1 ID. not good. it is like having two people with the same passport number. How would you like that? :S

Comment: Thank you for your answer @aless80

Answer (score 1):

In your actual code, you aren't doing anything in the function, you should simply select the right element and enable it.

Here's a simple snippet to enable the `length2`element when you select `rectangle`:

```js
function setShape(shape) {
  var elem = document.getElementById('geometric').value;
  console.log(elem);
  if (elem == 'square') {

  } else if (elem == 'circle') {

  } else if (elem == 'rectangle') {
    document.getElementsByName('length2')[0].removeAttribute('disabled');
  } else {

  }
}
```

```css
div {
  text-align: justify;
  position: Relative;
  border-width: 6px;
  width: 50%;
  left: 575px;
}
.duzen {
  text-align: justify;
  position: Relative;
  border-width: 6px;
  width: 50%;
  left: 625px;
}
.duzen1 {
  text-align: left;
  position: Relative;
  border-width: 100px;
  width: 50%;
  left: 540px;
}
.duzen2 {
  text-align: justify;
  position: Relative;
  border-width: 6px;
  width: 50%;
  left: 600px;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Shape:
    <select id="geometric" onchange="setShape(this)">
      <option value="square">Square</option>
      <option value="circle">Circle</option>
      <option value="rectangle">Rectangle</option>
      <option value="equilateraltriangle">Equilateral Triangle</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>

<div class="duzen">
  <form name="radBut">
    <input type="radio" name="shape1" value="perimeter">Perimeter
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="shape2" value="area">Area
    <br>
  </form>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>

<div class="duzen1">
  <form>
    <label>Side/Radius:</label>
    <input type="text" name="length1">
    <br>
    <label>Side2 for Rectangle:</label>
    <input type="text" name="length2" disabled>
    <br>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="duzen2">
  <form>
    <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Calculate">
    <input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset">
  </form>
</div>
<div class="duzen1">
  <form>
    <label>Result is:</label>
    <input type="text" name="length3">
    <br>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. @chsdk

Comment: @Theory You are welcome, I hope that's what you were looking for?

Comment: Can you help me again? I improved my function. @chsdk